# How to use Bootstrap data-toggle="validator" but let submit button enabled

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using Bootstrap 3 and i want to validate a form usign `data-toggle="validator"` only that i want the submit button enabled and warn the user if an input field is empty when submit is clicked. Any help would be really apreciated!

Here´s an example of my code

```
 <form id="checkout" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" 
         data-error="Please enter your name" placeholder="First name" />

         <button id="inputForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-prio-one">
                  <span>Submit</span>
         </button>
 </form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute `data-disable="false"` to the form tag and that should enable the `Submit` button.

`<form id="checkout" method="post" data-toggle="validator" data-disable="false">`

**Working Example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" data-disable="false">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" data-error="Please enter your name" id="Name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required />
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That enabled the submit button but how do i block the submit process and warn the user to input the information if the required input fields are not set?

Comment: You can find the working example above. Form submission is blocked until the First Name is entered. Also error messages are displayed to the user.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <form id="checkout" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" required="required" 
         data-error="Please enter your name" placeholder="First name" />

         <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

         <button id="inputForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-prio-one">
                  <span>Submit</span>
         </button>
 </form>
```

Try this code.

Comment: thanks you for the answer. The submit button is still disabled with that code